# Skip the validate.noEmpty() on ckeditor under condition

Tags: javascript, dialog, ckeditor

I'm currently creating a plugin for CKEditor wysiwyg box and this plugin call a dialog box, in this dialog box i have this element :

```
{
                            type :'text',
                            id : 'mail',
                            label : 'Adresse email',
                            validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.noEmpty("Explanation field cannot be empty")
},
```

and in the rest of my code i make it vanish or not depending on what the user wants... the question is when the element 'mail' is hidden (i use hide() to make hide it) how can i add a condition to skip the validate.regex([..]) when the field is not displayed ?

any help would be really great. 
tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i"ve found a way [here](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/wysiwyg-module-ckeditor-third-ultimate-end)

i just have to do this :

```
validate : function(){
     //some code 
     // must return a boolean true if you want to end the dialog else false
},
```

hope it could help someone :)